# From the ouput of Cross Distances operator of Rapid Miner, how to find 'Request set' row number/numbers from the 'Reference set'

Tags: dataset, similarity, rapidminer

I am new to Rapid Miner learning studio and its operators, while working with Rapid Miner i got stuck with a strange doubt and the issue is described issue -

1. I have a data set of 100 rows and i am inputting this set to 'Filter Example Range' operator
2. Output of 'Filter Example Range' operator will be 'Example set' and 'Original Set'
3. 'Filter Example Range' output is set as input to 'Cross Distances' operator. One is 'Request set' with - first example: 5 and last example: 5 (this is 'Example set' of 'Filter Example Range' and number 5 indicates the row number from the actual) The other input is 'Reference Set' - 100 rows of data (this is 'Original set' of Filter Example Range' operator)
4. From 'Cross Distances' operator we get three outputs. One is 'result set', 'Request set' and 'Reference set' (these both are inputs supplied too)

Now after getting the output from 'Cross Distances' operator, i want to know what is the row number of 'Request set' from the supplied 'reference set'.

Is there any chance to make a comparison of these both sets in 'Execute R' operator? or i request someone to please help me with any alternative.

Comment: Please remove the R tag unless you can justify its presence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Cross Distances` operator needs an `id` attribute and will add one if this is not present in the input example sets. The `id` attribute is a special attribute and is not used to calculate distances; only regular attributes are used for this. If the input example set contains an attribute called `id` that is regular, the operator changes this to be special thereby excluding it from the distance calculation.

The output is a distance between pairs and each pair is referred to using the `id` from each input.

So if the output looks like this (using the iris data set and selected the fifth one to be the request input and all the rest as the document input).

```
request document distance
id_5    id_5     0.0
id_5    id_1     0.141
```

it means that `id_5` in the request and `id_5` in the document are `0` distance apart, `id_5` in the request and `id_1` in the document are `0.141` apart.

For `id_1` and `id_5` in the iris data set, the data is as follows.

```
id    a1    a2    a3    a4
id_1  5.1   3.5   1.4   0.2
id_5  5.0   3.6   1.4   0.2
```

The distance is

`sqrt((5.1-5.0)^2 + (3.5-3.6)^2 + (1.4-1.4)^2 + (0.2-0.2)^2)`

which is `sqrt(0.01 + 0.01 + 0 + 0)`

and this becomes `0.141`.

Comment: Is this the example from "Cross Distances" operator info from RM studio? Just to know..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it in R with **Execute R** Operator. For this you need the `compare()` function from [compare](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/compare/compare.pdf) package. To compare two datasets with this function you need to check, if two columns from both datasets have the same type. By executing this function you can specify  different arguments, for example if you suggest that the second data set is just a piece of the first one, then  set "shorten=TRUE". Othe useful arguments are for example ignoreOrder, ignoreCase and ignoreColOrder.

What you can try in RapidMiner is just a **join** or **Generate Attributes** - for the second way you can extract macros from you "small" example set and check, if any row of the "larger" set hat these macros.

**Cross Distances** operator is IMHO to slow and not too much about data during the transforming procrss. Therefore it can be useful only at specific tasks.